# Show app icon badge on Android 8 via standard SDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

According to https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges
starting from Android 8 the OS allows to set up app icon notification badge, but I just can't get it to work.

```
            NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(activityContext);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                NotificationChannel nc = new NotificationChannel("ab", "chanelName", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                nc.setDescription("A chanel description here");
                nc.setShowBadge(true);

                NotificationManager nmm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nmm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(App.instance, "ab");
            nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.accept_icon);
            nb.setTicker("here is the ticker");
            nb.setContentText("Here content text");
            nb.setContentTitle("Here content title");
            nb.setNumber(5);
            nb.setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL);
            nm.notify(1, nb.build());
```

I'm using a Nexus 6P with android 8.1 .
It shows the notification in the system bar but not the badge on app icon.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is fine, but Nexus 6P does not support notification badges on the default launcher. You either need to test it on some other device (Pixel or something like that - of course you can use emulator with Oreo or above), or download a launcher with support for Oreo notification badges.

Somebody had a similar issue.
Read more here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/NykQ-lp1n2c

Comment: +1 for comment; 6p's default launcher does not support notification badges. 
Additionally, if you want to support some more launchers on older versions of android you may wanna look for a third-party libraries (like a ShortcutBadger or so)